# QBO/.NET SDK [Quickbooks Online] - How to remove empty invoice line item?

Tags: c#, .net, quickbooks

I have a new issue with quickbooks invoice.  Upon creation of an invoice I get all items I added plus one extra line item in my invoice.

How do I filter, remove, prevent this line from appearing?

**Here is what I have tried.**

```
//Find Item
var itemQueryService = new QueryService<Item>(qboContextoAuth);
Item item = itemQueryService.ExecuteIdsQuery("Select * From Item StartPosition 1 MaxResults 1").FirstOrDefault();

int idx = 0;

var lines = new List<Line>();

foreach (var orderItem in orderItems)
{

    //Line
    Line invoiceLine = new Line();

    //Line Description
    invoiceLine.Description = itemRepository.Get(i => i.ItemID == orderItem.ItemID).First().FullDescription;

    //Line Amount
    invoiceLine.Amount = orderItem.Price * orderItem.Quantity;

    invoiceLine.AmountSpecified = true;

    //Line Detail Type
    invoiceLine.DetailType = LineDetailTypeEnum.SalesItemLineDetail;

    invoiceLine.DetailTypeSpecified = true;

    //Line Sales Item Line Detail
    SalesItemLineDetail lineSalesItemLineDetail = new SalesItemLineDetail();


    //Line Sales Item Line Detail - ItemRef
    lineSalesItemLineDetail.ItemRef = new ReferenceType()
    {
        name = itemRepository.Get(i => i.ItemID == orderItem.ItemID).First().FullDescription,
                    Value = item.Id
               };

        //Line Sales Item Line Detail - UnitPrice
        lineSalesItemLineDetail.AnyIntuitObject = orderItem.Price; //33m;
        lineSalesItemLineDetail.ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType.UnitPrice;

        //Line Sales Item Line Detail - Qty
        lineSalesItemLineDetail.Qty = orderItem.Quantity; //10;
        lineSalesItemLineDetail.QtySpecified = true;

        //Line Sales Item Line Detail - TaxCodeRef
        //For US companies, this can be 'TAX' or 'NON

        /* lineSalesItemLineDetail.TaxCodeRef = new ReferenceType()
         {
             Value = "TAX"
         };*/

        //Line Sales Item Line Detail - ServiceDate 
        lineSalesItemLineDetail.ServiceDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
        lineSalesItemLineDetail.ServiceDateSpecified = true;

        //Assign Sales Item Line Detail to Line Item
        invoiceLine.AnyIntuitObject = lineSalesItemLineDetail;

        //Assign Line Item to Invoice
        //invoice.Line = new Line[] { invoiceLine };
        lines.Add(invoiceLine);

        //TxnTaxDetail
        /*TxnTaxDetail txnTaxDetail = new TxnTaxDetail();
        txnTaxDetail.TxnTaxCodeRef = new ReferenceType()
        {
            name = stateTaxCode.Name,
            Value = stateTaxCode.Id
        };
        Line taxLine = new Line();
        taxLine.DetailType = LineDetailTypeEnum.TaxLineDetail;
        TaxLineDetail taxLineDetail = new TaxLineDetail();

        //Assigning the fist Tax Rate in this Tax Code
        taxLineDetail.TaxRateRef = stateTaxCode.SalesTaxRateList.TaxRateDetail[0].TaxRateRef;
        taxLine.AnyIntuitObject = taxLineDetail;
        txnTaxDetail.TaxLine = new Line[] { taxLine };
        invoice.TxnTaxDetail = txnTaxDetail;
        */

        idx++;
    }
```

**Removal Code**

```
Item item2 = itemQueryService.ExecuteIdsQuery("Select * From Item StartPosition 2 MaxResults 1").FirstOrDefault();

//Line Sales Item Line Detail - ItemRef
SalesItemLineDetail lineDetail = new SalesItemLineDetail();
Line removeLine = new Line();

lineDetail.ItemRef = new ReferenceType()
{
    Value = item2.Id
};
removeLine.AnyIntuitObject = lineDetail;

lines.RemoveAt(1);
```

Related question:

[Quickbooks Online Accounting - How to add multiple line items in an invoice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45174403/quickbooks-online-accounting-how-to-add-multiple-line-items-in-an-invoice)

Comment: Why  can't you just identify the extra line before it is inserted and just skip it so it does not end up in the invoice?

Comment: My array of invoice line items has the correct amount of items in it.  It's just that I get an extra empty item in my invoice.

Comment: What is the data source for `orderItems`?

Comment: This is from an application / internal database which might be possible for me to explain on this but in short it consists of price and item name.

Answer (score 2):

Check that extra line item's Detail Type, It must be SubTotalLineDetail. It's SubTotal of all line items. Then you can skip it on it's enum type.